# Kubernetes Volume snapshot: Why is restoresize when we list snapshot not in sync with actual volume size

Tags: kubernetes, snapshot, persistent-volume-claims, csi-driver

I created a PVC and wrote 50G of data to the volume after mounting it to a pod.
Created volumesnapshot and restored volume from snapshot.
Verified 50G of data is present in new volume from second application pod.

Now when I do `kubectl get volumesnapshot`, I see

```
kubectl get volumesnapshot
NAME                            READYTOUSE   SOURCEPVC                    SOURCESNAPSHOTCONTENT   RESTORESIZE   SNAPSHOTCLASS        SNAPSHOTCONTENT                                    CREATIONTIME   AGE
snapshot-csi-block-pvc-custom   true         csi-block-pvc-custom-three                           1Gi           vpc-block-snapshot   snapcontent-c2045897-7a69-4fd5-851d-b11bbade8a2f   19m            19m
```

I dont understand why `RESTORESIZE` is 1G. Have I missed something to understand in this snapshot concept.

Comment: To use volume snapshots on GKE, you must meet the following [Requirements](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/persistent-volumes/volume-snapshots#requirements) . Kindly check whether these requirements are met in your environments.

Suggesting this official doc links of [Volume Snapshot](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volume-snapshots/) and [Restore Volume from Snapshot Support](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/#volume-snapshot-and-restore-volume-from-snapshot-support) .

Comment: Does the above comment help you to resolve your concern or else let us know where you are strucked at?